# PHP session sometimes is lost when using session_regenerate_id

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have strange behavior in my website, when session is started with the following option:

session_regenerate_id(true);

Sometimes when browsing, user gets kicked from members area, I get errors that session variables are undefined at that moment, for example:

[Tue Oct 29 13:37:39 2013] [error] [client 78.62.xx.xx] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: origid in /home/rolandas/public_html/domain.com/members/send_sms.php on line 115, referer: http://www.domain.com/members/actions.php

But if I do not use session ID regeneration, everything works fine all the time. What could be an issue? Is there a problem with my server?

Comment: How are the requests executed?
What can happen, is that you regenerate an id, while another request is executing with the invalid session id (in $_COOKIE). maybe session_regenerate_id(false) will work for you.