# PHP Session not carrying

Tags: php, class, session

I know this has been asked multiple times, I've scoured SO, tried every combination provided and every method I can think of, and I'm still at loss..

Here's the scenario:
I've just wrote up and fully tested a login system. The code processes as it should, but the `$_SESSION` isn't carrying over.
Assuming I've entered the correct details:
I've checked multiple different things. `print_r($_SESSION)` returns "Array( [user] => 1 )" on the index (where the login is) upon form submission, but returns "Array( )" on the next page (dashboard.php)

Here's my index.php

```
<?php
include(__DIR__ . '/includes/class_mtg_sessions.php');
$session = new Session();
$session->start_session('_mtg', true);
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
    exit;
}
include(__DIR__ . '/includes/header.php');
?><div id="templatemo_main">
    <div class="content_wrapper">
        <div class="col_1">
            <h2>Client Area</h2>
            <p><img src="<?php echo IMAGE_URL; ?>/icon_04.png" alt="Image 4" class="img_fl" /></p>
            <p><div id="contact_form" class="col_2 left">
                <h3>Login</h3><?php
                if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    $str = array('name', 'password');
                    foreach($str as $what) {
                        $_POST[$what] = isset($_POST[$what]) && is_string($_POST[$what]) ? strtolower($db->escape(trim($_POST[$what]))) : null;
                        if(empty($_POST[$what]))
                            $mtg->error("You didn't enter a valid ".$what);
                    }
                    $selectUser = $db->query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE ((LOWER(`username`) = '".$_POST['name']."') OR (LOWER(`email`) = '".$_POST['name']."'))");
                    if(!$db->num_rows($selectUser))
                        $mtg->error("There doesn't appear to be anyone on record with that ".(filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username'));
                    $select = $db->query("SELECT `id`, `username` FROM `users` WHERE LOWER(`username`) = '".$_POST['name']."' OR LOWER(`email`) = '".$_POST['name']."' AND `password` = '".$mtg->fuzzehCrypt($_POST['password'])."'");
                    if(!$db->num_rows($select))
                        $mtg->error("Invalid ".(filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username')."/password combination");
                    $row = $db->fetch_row($select);
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $row['id'];
                    $mtg->success("Welcome back ".$mtg->format($row['username'])."!<br />Redirecting you now...<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3; url=dashboard.php' />");
                    echo "</div></div></div></div>";
                    include(__DIR__ . '/includes/footer.php');
                    exit;
                }
                ?><form method="post" name="contact" action="index.php">
                    <div class="col_3">
                        <label for="name">ID</label>
                        <input name="name" type="text" class="required input_field" id="name" placeholder="Username/Email" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col_3 no_margin_right">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input name="password" type="password" class="required input_field" id="password" maxlength="30" placeholder="Password" required />
                    </div>

                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit_btn left" />
                    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" class="submit_btn right" />
                </form>
            </div></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content_wrapper">
        <div class="col_1">
            <h2>New member?</h2>
            <p><div id="contact_form" class="col_2 left">
                Don't have an account? <a href='register.php'>Sign up now!</a><br />
                It's completely free and it allows you to track everything about your order(s), place new orders, directly manage how your current order is being processed and much more!
            </div></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><?php
include(__DIR__ . '/includes/footer.php');
```

Here's the dashboard.php

```
<?php
include(__DIR__ . '/includes/class_mtg_sessions.php');
$session = new Session();
$session->start_session('_mtg', true);
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
include(__DIR__ . '/includes/header.php');
$mtg->userdata($_SESSION['user']);

?>    <div id="templatemo_main">
        <div class="content_wrapper">
            <div class="col_1">
                <h2>Client Area</h2>
                <p><img src="<?php echo IMAGE_URL; ?>/icon_04.png" alt="Image 4" class="img_fl" /></p>
                <p><div id="contact_form" class="col_2 left">
                    <h3>Dashboard</h3>
                    Dashboard coming soon
                </div></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><?php
include(__DIR__ . '/includes/footer.php');
```

And finally, the session class I'm using.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
class Session {
    function __construct() {
        session_set_save_handler(
            array(&$this, 'open'),
            array(&$this, 'close'),
            array(&$this, 'read'),
            array(&$this, 'write'),
            array(&$this, 'destroy'),
            array(&$this, 'gc')
        );
        register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
    }

    function start_session($session_name, $secure) {
        if(in_array('sha512', hash_algos()))
            ini_set('session.hash_function', 'sha512');
        ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 5);
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);

        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
        session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams['lifetime'], $cookieParams['path'], $cookieParams['domain'], $secure, true);
        session_name($session_name);
        session_start();
        session_regenerate_id(true);
    }

    function open() {
        include(__DIR__ . '/definitions.php');
        $this->db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_BASE) or exit("Couldn't connect to the database");
        return true;
    }

    function close() {
        $this->db->close();
        return true;
    }

    function read($id) {
        if(!isset($this->read_stmt))
            $this->read_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `data` FROM `sessions` WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1");
        $this->read_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $this->read_stmt->execute();
        $this->read_stmt->store_result();
        $this->read_stmt->bind_result($data);
        $this->read_stmt->fetch();
        $key  = $this->getkey($id);
        $data = $this->decrypt($data, $key);
        return $data;
    }

    function write($id, $data) {
        $key  = $this->getkey($id);
        $data = $this->encrypt($data, $key);
        $time = time();
        if(!isset($this->w_stmt))
            $this->w_stmt = $this->db->prepare("REPLACE INTO `sessions` (`id`, `set_time`, `data`, `session_key`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)") or trigger_error(mysqli_error($this->db));
        $this->w_stmt->bind_param('siss', $id, $time, $data, $key);
        $this->w_stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }

    function destroy($id) {
        if(!isset($this->delete_stmt))
            $this->delete_stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM `sessions` WHERE `id` = ?") or trigger_error(mysqli_error($this->db));
        $this->delete_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $this->delete_stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }

    function gc($max) {
        if(!isset($this->gc_stmt))
            $this->gc_stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM `sessions` WHERE `set_time` < ?") or trigger_error(mysqli_error($this->db));
        @$this->gc_stmt->bind_param('s', (time() - $max));
        $this->gc_stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }

    private function getkey($id) {
        if(!isset($this->key_stmt))
            $this->key_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `session_key` FROM `sessions` WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1") or trigger_error(mysqli_error($this->db));
        $this->key_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $this->key_stmt->execute();
        $this->key_stmt->store_result();
        if($this->key_stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            $this->key_stmt->bind_result($key);
            $this->key_stmt->fetch();
            return $key;
        } else {
            $random_key = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));
            return $random_key;
        }
    }

    private function encrypt($data, $key) {
        $salt      = 'agar16565!sfrb0a0$£%^&njswdUEB(*£8034672839ngrwu*(£89bgaq90hmw4n';
        $key       = substr(hash('sha256', $salt . $key . $salt), 0, 32);
        if(!function_exists('mcrypt_get_iv_size'))
            exit("mCrypt not enabled");
        $iv_size   = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv        = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
        return $encrypted;
    }

    private function decrypt($data, $key) {
        $salt      = 'agar16565!sfrb0a0$£%^&njswdUEB(*£8034672839ngrwu*(£89bgaq90hmw4n';
        $key       = substr(hash('sha256', $salt . $key . $salt), 0, 32);
        if(!function_exists('mcrypt_get_iv_size'))
            exit("mCrypt not enabled");
        $iv_size   = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv        = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return $decrypted;
    }
}
```

Database structure for the `users` and `sessions` tables (using `SHOW CREATE TABLE`):

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `id` char(128) NOT NULL,
  `set_time` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `session_key` char(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `session_key` (`session_key`),
  KEY `set_time` (`set_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `verified` enum('Yes','No','Flagged') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  `ver_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `type` enum('standard','admin') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'standard',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `type` (`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Now, I'm using the same class on a different site hosted on the same server and it works absolutely fine.
I've checked the permissions for the tmp directory, and those are fine (I have WHM/SSH access)
All classes that are supposed to connect to the database have connected perfectly fine with no issues

Someone please put me out of my misery and save what's left of my sanity!

[edit][1] 
I've tried w00d's method (of setting the `session_regenerate_id(true)` to `false`), still no luck)
I've also tried completely removing the `session_regenerate_id(true);` and the same issue remains

[edit][2]
Removing the call to the session class and using the standard `session_start()` appears to "fix" it but, in doing so, I've unwillingly disabled the database system.

As I've said, the class works perfectly on another site using the same server, so what could possibly be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem probably here:

```
    session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Why? [taken here](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id)

> bool session_regenerate_id ([ bool $delete_old_session = false ] )
>   session_regenerate_id() will replace the current session id with a new
>   one, and keep the    current session information.

Every time `start_session` is executed, it will replace the information.
You can try to remove the `true` and see if it work as expected.

Comment: Setting to false returns the same issue. Thank you though

Comment: why do you want to regenerate the id? see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656129/php-session-sometimes-is-lost-when-using-session-regenerate-id

Comment: Mostly to keep the database up to date and clear of multiple entries.

Comment: can you make a simplest case: remove all the session settings, only session_start() and check your session? also print `session_save_path()` and check that directory. If it's correct you should see some file with session_id as the name, see if any data is stored

Comment: Just to clarify: You're requesting that I remove any calls to the class and use PHP's native `session_start` instead? If so, done, and working perfectly. Which means... hmm... original post updated

Comment: yes, or you can continue to use the class but on start_session, just use session_start()

Comment: If It works, you can slowly add in each feature to see which one causes the problem, my another guess is that the `session_set_cookie_params` may cause the problem, since the first time when you do the `session_get_cookie_params` there is nothing in the session to begin with.

Comment: I see. Well, thank you for you help. Invaluable! I've marked your answer as the right one. Hopefully, I won't have to bother you again. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**the reason  "session may be in use "**

place hard coded `session_write_close();` after session job is over

**It should be noted that register_shutdown_function() does not guarantee session_write_close(); as you have done**